# With Generex lib getting non-human readable result with one of the regex

Tags: java, regex

With regex : `(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,}` 
getting junk character in output

Code Snippet :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String regex = "(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,}";
    Generex generex = new Generex(regex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String generatedString = generex.random();
        System.out.println(generatedString);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
?=]Pឥᨋ腻밡칃辽
髖[i蓼跏鎞Ẕ存Չ橠
?=Wꎿ샲햪猪ꖨ㚦ꥎ
?=`爕y繇貏⩜?≙擟岡캍䯮
?=᲻u눰﫻?饔ᆴ䏎㮞
```

Comment: Not non-human, I'd say asian or like this

Comment: But with regex like [a-zA-Z0-9\[\]@#$!\*%&()]{4,25} , getting result in english language only . Output shared by me in post seems to me  as junk that'w why i mentioned non human-readable. Please correct me if my observation is not correct. And how can i get proper result with shared regex

Comment: dot mean any character even the chines characters this is why you get this results

Comment: From what I remember, libraries like this ignore lookarounds. Only use consuming patterns.

Comment: Thanks @azro , YCF_L , Wiktor Stribiżew for the inputs.